# AWS CLI does not use credentials set with environment variables

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have a simple Test.bat file that is as follows

```
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY=yyy
set AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-1

aws ec2 describe-instances
```

When I run this batch file, it is listing the instances from my production account. When I checked my user profile location at C:\Users\testuser.aws , the  credentials file has the accesss key and secret key of my production account.

My question is per the aws documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)  environment variables takes precedence over the credentials file. But why does this not work for me ? I would want the instances to be listed for the account specified in the bat file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWSCLI will look for the following environment variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE
```

It doesn't look like you are using the right env var names.